# Stacklayout backgroundColor binding with MVVM

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I'm attempting to get my head around MVVM with XamarinForms and I'm slightly confused with regards to proper partitioning of functionality:

I have a main page, MainPage.xaml, which includes a stacklayout:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MainPageStackLayout">
...
</StackLayout>
```

Within this stacklayout I have Picker which is bound as follows:

```
<Picker Title="Select a background colour"
        TitleColor="Black"
        TextColor="Black"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyColours}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding selectedBackGroundColour}" SelectedIndexChanged="BackGroundColourPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Following the article from microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-monkeyapppicker/):
I have a "View" which basically defines the layout of my page.

A "ViewModel" which holds an IList "MyColours" and a variable "SelectedBackGroundColour".

A "Model" which defines the MyColour class. A MyColour has a string name and a Xamarin.Forms.Color (from a hex value, both populated on start up).

This all works fine. I can start up the app and the Picker populates with the colours I add to "MyColours". If I change the index then my SelectedBackGroundColour also updates, has the correct name and a different RGB value.

However, I'm lost as to where I would tie in the updating of the actual background colour of the MainPageStackLayout. The View (MainPage.xaml.cs) picks up the "BackGroundColourPicker_SelectedIndexChanged" event but what is the standard practice for reading from the view model (where SelectedBackGround colour is actual defined ?)

I have a feeling I can bind Background colour in the MainPageStackLayout xaml view so I wont have to catch the selected index change event.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess that you want to change MainPage StackLayout BackGround color by Picker value, am I right?

If yes, please follow the steps below.

Firstly, please confirm that you implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface to notify SelectedBackGroundColour changed.

Then there are full code, please take a look:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MainPageStacklayout" BackgroundColor="{Binding selectedBackGroundColour.color}">
        <Picker
            x:Name="picker1"
            Title="Select a background colour"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyColours}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selectedBackGroundColour}"
            TextColor="Black"
            TitleColor="Black" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page5 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyColour> MyColours { get; set; }
    private MyColour _selectedBackGroundColour;

    public MyColour selectedBackGroundColour
    {
        get { return _selectedBackGroundColour; }
        set
        {
            _selectedBackGroundColour = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selectedBackGroundColour");
        }
    }

    public Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyColours = new ObservableCollection<MyColour>()
        {
            new MyColour(){name="red",color=Color.Red},
            new MyColour(){name="gray",color=Color.Gray},
            new MyColour(){name="BlueViolet",color=Color.BlueViolet}
        };
        selectedBackGroundColour = MyColours[0];
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class MyColour
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]